# How do I import a nested jinja macro?

Tags: jinja2, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I would like to import a nested jinja macro into a rest file and call it.

So we have main.rst file which imports a collection_of_macros.jinja and inside the collection_of_jinja_macros.jinja is a list of imports which are importing jinja macros.

```
main.rest file has:
{% import 'path/collection_of_jinja_macros.jinja' as macros%}
{{macros.macro1() }}

then the collection_of_jinja_macros.jinja has 
{% include 'path/macro1.jinja' %}
{% include 'path/macro2.jinja' %}
```

I've tried using include,import, and toctree syntax to pull in the macros but I can never find success.

The rest file cannot never resolve the macro lookup.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same question and found a way that works. The trick is that your `collection_of_jinja_macros.jinja` needs to not only import the macros, but also needs to export those collections of macros with a variable declared using `{% set %}`.

Updating your example:

```
# collection_of_jinja_macros.jinja

{% include 'path/macro1.jinja' as macro1 %}
{% include 'path/macro2.jinja' as macro2 %}

{% set macro1 = macro1 %}
{% set macro2 = macro2 %}
```

If you do this, then the following works:

```
# main.rest

{% import 'path/collection/of_jinja_macros.jinja' as macros %}

{{ macros.macro1.someMacroName() }}
{{ macros.macro2.someOtherMacroName() }}
```

I wish it were sufficient to use the `import ... as` syntax.